# Are XmlParser and XmlSlurper namespace aware by default?

Tags: xml, groovy, namespaces

When answering this question [How to read values from XML Request and write into XML Response using Groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33411390/how-to-read-values-from-xml-request-and-write-into-xml-response-using-groovy/33413215#33413215) related to namespaces (SOAP) with [`XmlSlurper`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html) and [`XmlParser`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/util/XmlParser.html), I realized that I was actually not able to tell if they are *non-namespace-aware* by default.

While ***documentation*** says so (***non-namespace-aware by default***):

[**`XmlSlurper`**](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html#XmlSlurper())

> XmlSlurper ()
>
> Creates a non-validating and non-namespace-aware
>   XmlSlurper which does not allow DOCTYPE declarations in documents.

[**`XmlParser`**](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/util/XmlParser.html#XmlParser())

> XmlParser ()
>
> Creates a non-validating and non-namespace-aware
>   XmlParser which does not allow DOCTYPE declarations in documents.

***Code*** is exactly the opposite (***namespace-aware by default***):

[*XmlSlurper*](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-xml/src/main/java/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.java):

```
public XmlSlurper() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
    this(false, true);
}
```

[*XmlParser*](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-xml/src/main/java/groovy/util/XmlParser.java):

```
public XmlParser() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
    this(false, true);
}
```

I found also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669766/namespace-handling-in-groovys-xmlslurper/8670254#8670254) claiming that XMLSlurper is non-namespace aware by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Groovy 2.4.6, the documentation is wrong:

```
/**
 * Creates a non-validating and non-namespace-aware <code>XmlSlurper</code> which does not allow DOCTYPE declarations in documents.
 *
 * @throws ParserConfigurationException if no parser which satisfies the requested configuration can be created.
 * @throws SAXException for SAX errors.
 */
public XmlSlurper() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
    this(false, true);
}
```

It actually creates a namespace-aware parser (second parameter true).

There is also a bug I reported where the namespace prefixes are not handled properly: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7781. Fortunately another user issued a PR to fix. Someone should put in a PR to fix the documentation issue as well as this has caused confusion to myself and others multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

I think that documentation is wrong and `XmlSlurper` and `XmlParser` are *namespace-aware* by default:

```
def text = '''<person xmlns:city="http://localhost/">
    <name>jalopaba</name>
    <city:name>Valladolid</city:name>
</person>'''

// XmlSlurper is namespace aware, since new XmlSlurper() --> new XmlSlurper(false, true)
def slurped_person = new XmlSlurper().parseText(text)
assert 'jalopabaValladolid' == slurped_person.name.text() // :name and :name from city
assert 'jalopaba' == slurped_person.':name'.text() // aware of default namespace
assert '' == slurped_person.'city:name'.text() // city namespace not declared

// but you need to make the resulting GPathResult aware of the concrete namespace
slurped_person = new XmlSlurper().parseText(text).declareNamespace([city: 'http://localhost/'])
assert 'jalopabaValladolid' == slurped_person.name.text() // :name and :name from city
assert 'jalopaba' == slurped_person.':name'.text() // aware of default namespace
assert 'Valladolid' == slurped_person.'city:name'.text() // city namespace declared

// If you make XmlSlurper not namespace aware, it uses the whole element string
slurped_person = new XmlSlurper(false, false).parseText(text)
assert 'jalopaba' == slurped_person.name.text() // just element 'name'
assert '' == slurped_person.':name'.text() // not aware of default namespace
assert 'Valladolid' == slurped_person.'city:name'.text() // using the whole element string (it seems to be namespace aware, but it's not)

// And when it is not namespace aware, nothing changes declaring namespaces
slurped_person = new XmlSlurper(false, false).parseText(text).declareNamespace([city: 'http://localhost/'])
assert 'jalopaba' == slurped_person.name.text() // just element 'name'
assert '' == slurped_person.':name'.text() // not aware of default namespace
assert 'Valladolid' == slurped_person.'city:name'.text() // using the whole element string (it seems to be namespace aware, but it's not)

def c = new Namespace('http://localhost/', 'city')
assert c.name instanceof QName // => new QName('http://localhost/', 'name', 'city')

// XmlParser is namespace aware, since new XmlParser() --> new XmlParser(false, true)
def parsed_person = new XmlParser().parseText(text)
assert parsed_person.toString() == 'person[attributes={}; value=[name[attributes={}; value=[jalopaba]], {http://localhost/}name[attributes={}; value=[Valladolid]]]]'
assert 'jalopaba' == parsed_person.name.text() // default namespace
assert 'jalopaba' == parsed_person[new QName('name')].text() // default namespace
assert 'jalopabaValladolid' == parsed_person[new QName('http://localhost/', 'name')].text() // aware of namespace and empty string as prefix
assert 'Valladolid' == parsed_person[new QName('http://localhost/', 'name', 'it_does_not_matter')].text() // aware of namespace, prefix does not matter
assert '' == parsed_person[new QName('http://wrong_namespace/', 'name', 'city')].text() // aware of namespace, wrong URI with good prefix gets nothing
assert 'Valladolid' == parsed_person[c.name].text()
assert 'Valladolid' == parsed_person.'city:name'.text() // using the whole element string

// With XmlParser not namespace aware...
parsed_person = new XmlParser(false, false).parseText(text)
assert parsed_person.toString() == 'person[attributes={xmlns:city=http://localhost/}; value=[name[attributes={}; value=[jalopaba]], city:name[attributes={}; value=[Valladolid]]]]'
assert 'jalopaba' == parsed_person.name.text()
assert 'jalopaba' == parsed_person[new QName('name')].text()
assert 'jalopaba' == parsed_person[new QName('http://localhost/', 'name')].text() // ignores namespace, only uses 'name' string
assert '' == parsed_person[new QName('http://localhost/', 'name', 'wrong_prefix')].text() // not aware of namespace, the only important thing is prefix
assert 'Valladolid' == parsed_person[new QName('http://wrong_namespace/', 'name', 'city')].text() // wrong namespace but not aware, the only important thing is prefix
assert 'Valladolid' == parsed_person[c.name].text()
assert 'Valladolid' == parsed_person.'city:name'.text()
```