# How to use XMLSlurper with JMeter JSR223 assertion?

Tags: xml, groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I am trying to extract text from an element, using JSR 223 assertion and [`XmlSlurper`](https://www.google.com/search?q=XmlSlurper&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

```
offer=vars.get('CurrentOfferUnderTest')
def xml = new XmlSlurper(false,true).parseText(SampleResult.getResponseDataAsString())
if(offer=='410012'){
    //assert xml.ResultHeader.ResultCode.text()=='102020006'
    log.info(xml.Envelope.Body.LoanManageResultMsg.ResultHeader.ResultCode.text())
    log.info(xml.'*'.ResultCode.text())
    a=xml.'*'.find{node -> node.name()=='ns2:ResultCode'} //regardless of namespace, same result
    assert a.text()=='102020006'
}
```

whenever I do log just the `xml` var, I see text in the logs, when I try ad navigate as per above I get blanks\nulls. even when doing `xml.Envelope.text()` hence I added the namespace aware boolean. It didn't really help. What am I doing wrong?

XML excerpt

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns4:LoanManageResultMsg xmlns:ns4="http://www.p.com/wsdl/manageloanmgr"
                               xmlns:ns2="http://www.p.com/wsdl/shared"
                               xmlns:ns3="http://www.p.com/wsdl/loan"
                               xmlns:ns5="http://www.p.com/wsdl/newsubscriber"
                               xmlns:ns6="http://www.p.com/wsdl/query"
                               xmlns:ns7="http://www.p.com/wsdl/subscribe">
         <ResultHeader>
            <ns2:CommandId>LoanManage</ns2:CommandId>
            <ns2:Version>1</ns2:Version>
            <ns2:TransactionId>6</ns2:TransactionId>
            <ns2:SequenceId>4u6w6qry3</ns2:SequenceId>
            <ns2:ResultCode>102020006</ns2:ResultCode>
            <ns2:ResultDesc>Operation invalid.</ns2:ResultDesc>
            <ns2:OrderId>0</ns2:OrderId>
```

this did not help [Are XmlParser and XmlSlurper namespace aware by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33418826/are-xmlparser-and-xmlslurper-namespace-aware-by-default)

Comment: albeit not how I envisioned, i'm just using an xpath2 extractor and validating it via a ruleset later. Would be nice to know how to do it though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should be using `Envelope` in your [GPath](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_gpath) because your `xml` object resolves to the [Soap Envelope](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/soap/soap_envelope.htm) already.

[image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Processing XML](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html)
- [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)